What are these hard black dots on PCB?

I have this LCD from Adafruit. On the bottom side, it has these hard black spots, slightly domed. I'm wondering what they are, and how they are produced.
There are clearly traces running to these, and markings for U1 and U2, so they're covering some chips - but why? Is the chip fragile? Is it to make it harder to reverse engineer?
I also noticed that they're very neatly applied, but if I compare mine to the image on Adafruit's website accessed from here you can see they look slightly different - so it seems likely to me this is some kind of liquid that's dispensed and cured.

I'd love to know what and why.

It's called COB (chip-on-board) technology.
It is a cheaper (and generally less reliable) method of assembling chips onto a PCB. It requires reasonably fine traces and it likely requires a small bit of gold plating for wire bonding.
In the case of your LCD module, the gold plating is required anyway since there are zebra connectors between the LCD glass and the PCB.
By using the bare dies, the cost of the epoxy packaging (including the internal wirebonding) is saved. The die is glued down directly to the PCB, then an automated wire bonder maniacally attaches ~1mil aluminum wire bonding wires between the gold-plated PCB and the die itself in a kind of stitching operation. The parameters of bonding to a PCB are different from bonding to a leadframe, and more challenging in some respects. Sometimes the manufacturer of the product allows for both a bare die and for a packaged IC. Sparkfun got the below photo from a factory that makes multimeters using COB techniques. Again, there is an LCD display involved and zebra connectors. You can see that they chose to use a dual footprint so they can use either a packaged IC or COB. Whether that's for availability reasons or whether some of their customers specify the packaged chips we do not know.

When the wire bonds are completed a drip of epoxy is put on top to protect the fragile wire bonds that are otherwise looping through thin air.
This is actually something that can be done in small quantity, however even a manual wire bonder is not cheap, and getting a reliable supply of small quantities of bare dies is not always easy. So it tends to be limited in application to high volumes of relatively inexpensive items, or special applications where size is very important.

The best answer IMO.

Epoxy covering an integrated circuit die. The die is attached to the board and wired-bonded to the PCB. The epoxy protects the die and wiring from mechanical damage. This is often found in mass produced consumer electronics.

Glob-Top ``Glob tops are encapsulations that protect fragile semiconductor die and wire bonds. They are placed over chips as an environmental barrier, mechanical reinforcement, or tamper proof layer.''


The "dots" are actual integrated circuits in the "die" format wired by some welding technique directly to PCB. The black plastic dome is just a protection of dies and wires.
